# How to put a character variable into another character variable both coming from 2 differents structures?

Tags: c, types, tree, structure

I have to affect a character from a structure to another and I have a mistake but I don't get where is it coming from.
Here is the .txt file :

```
stabilimetre    stabilimetre    Nom:Mas+SG
```

Here is the first structure :

```
typedef struct s_node
{
    char letter; //This one 
    struct s_node* f_letters[26];
    word* flechies;
}t_node;

typedef struct s_tree
{
    t_node* root;
}t_tree;
```

And here is the second :

```
typedef struct
{
    char content[100];//This one 
    char base_word[100];
    int nature;
    int genre;
    int nombre;
    int temps;
    int personne;
}word;
```

In this case I want to put one of the character from content to letter from the other structure.
So this is how I procede :

```
int main () {
    FILE *fp;
    char str[5000];
    char type[100];
    t_tree Letter;
    t_node* temp;
    Letter.root=NULL;
    t_node first;

    fp = fopen("dico_reducted.txt" , "r"); 

    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1); 
    }

    while (fgets (str, sizeof(str), fp)!=NULL) {
        word A;
        sscanf(str,"%s\t%s\t%s:%s",&A.content, &A.base_word, &type); 
        Letter.root = &first;
        first.letter = 'N';
        first.f_letters[0] = temp; 
        temp->letter = A.content[0]; //This is the line where the error is coming from
    }
    fclose(fp); // Close the file

    return 0;
}
```

This other line take a text from a .txt file and the first word is putted inside A.content.
I'm actually trying to create a tree with the letter of this word.

I've tried to find out if the type are different between A.content[0] and temp.letter but it seems to be the same.

Actually the output I have now is nothing but an error.
The final output would be a tree with letter in every node.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the first 10 lines or so of `dico_reducted.txt` properly formatted

Comment: Also what is `t_tree` ? Show a [mcve] along with expected and actual output.

Comment: That line is not the source of the problem.

Comment: @0___________ I've tried to put printf between every step and the printf before do appear but after it, it crash. That's why I thing it's coming from this line.

Comment: @0___________ I've tried to delete this line and rerun and this is working. The return 0 work while before it was returning an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp is not initialized. It not pointed any real object.